# Synchronous call of meteor method from client (angular) side

Tags: angularjs, meteor

I got completely stuck on trying to make a synchronous call of method. I am trying to get list of clients from server side (simplified version, originally it is a call for another API) and print this list on a webpage.

Client side code (Angular 1):

```
import template from './clientsList.html';
import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor';

class ClientsList {
    constructor() {
        console.log('First'); 
        Meteor.call('getClients', function (error, response) {
            if (error) {
                // If our API returned an error, we'd see it in the console.
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                console.log(response);
                this.clients = response;
            }
        });
        console.log('Second');
    }   
}

const name = 'clientsList';

export default angular.module(name, [
    angularMeteor
]).component(name, {
    template,
    controllerAs: name,
    controller: ClientsList
})
}
```

Server Side code (Meteor):

```
    import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor';
    var Future = Npm.require( 'fibers/future' );

    Meteor.methods({
          // Synchronous method
        'getClients': function () {
            // Create our future instance.
            var future = new Future(); 
var clients = {[Name: 'Peter']};     
            future.return( clients ); 
            // preventinvg method from completing until the future receives a value
            return future.wait();
        }
    });
```

Template:

```
 <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="client in clientsList.clients">
                {{client.Name}}

        </li>
    </ul>
```

Seems that my use of Future to make server side code work synchronously does not work. This what I get in my console:

```
First
Second
Array[1]
```

Expecting:

```
First 
Array[1]
Second
```

I would very appreciate for any help.

Comment: You have the future in a synchronous section of code (strictly inside the method). This would be useful if your method was itself making an asynchronous call but it's not. You need promises on the client. Also the name of your method (`getClients`) implies you are using a method to fetch data when you could use pub-sub.

Comment: @MichelFloyd, The OP suggests that the original server code calls an API, so it is potentially asynchronous. @OP, note that you can use [the http package](https://docs.meteor.com/api/http.html) in a synchronous fashion on the server when making your API calls. Even if you are using a third-party API library, you can wrap it using [`wrapasync`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-wrapAsync), but using `Future` if this is what you prefer.

Comment: Right but look at his code where he makes the async call on the client but expects `First, Array[1], Second` which can't happen no matter what he does on the server because `Meteor.call()` itself is async.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server-side code (if it works correctly) simply makes the call resolve when the future resolves.

This makes the client callback be called when the server has actual data for it, but still, it will not be synchronous (there is no way to make it synchronous on the client).

You can try to use [promises](https://github.com/deanius/meteor-promise), [async/await](https://forums.meteor.com/t/start-using-async-await-instead-of-promises-and-callbacks/17037) (ES7) or [observables](https://forums.meteor.com/t/subscribe-data-in-service-using-rxjs-5/23258) (RxJS) to simplify your code, but it will always be asynchronous behind the scenes.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense now! So when I am setting this.clients = response; in the client side, how can I make it shown on the template? Because I was supposing that this is because my code is async, however, according to you, it is always asynchronous on client side. So my clients are not shown on a template. How to resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

Method call from client to server can not be synchronous. You should read this [Meteor.call](https://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html#Meteor-call)

Answer (score 0):

what you're seeing is correct. the call from the client to the server is asynchronous, there's nothing you can do about that.

in your template, you're essentially doing 3 things: logging 'First', making a async call, and logging 'Second'.

sometime later, your async call returns and you enter the callback of the Meteor call. that's when you do your 3rd console.log().

i realize you're handling the server call itself synchronously, but that has nothing to do with the async behavior between client and server.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to make template "wait" when asynchronous method in Angular will get the response and assign it to this.clients value? Because right now it seems that it launches the template immediately without waiting until constructor will fully finish and assign value to this.clients variable.